# How to async load data for a BindablePicker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm using a *BindablePicker* to display some data in my Xamarin.Forms App. The picker is bound to a ObservableCollection in the ViewModel:

```
<Picker 
   SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedObjectIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}"
/>
```

After the view gets activated by the *Autofac*  Inversion of Control-Container, I'm loading the picker's data using an async service and add them to the Collection of the picker's source:

```
  public override async Task OnActivating()
    {
        var data = await this.dataService.GetAllObjectsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        this.objects.AddRange(data);
        this.objects.ForEach(f => this.ObjectList.Add(f.attr1 + @" - " + f.attr2));
        this.SelectedObjectIndex= 0;
    }
```

This works in 90% of all cases, however, sometimes the data don't get loaded and displayed. I thought it was because of a background thread created by the async call, so I tried to force the update of the DataSource on the UI-Thread:

```
public override async Task OnActivating()
        {
            var data = await dataService.GetAllObjectsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            this.objects.AddRange(data);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                () =>
                    {
                        this.objects.ForEach(f => this.ObjectList.Add(f.attr1+ @" - " + f.attr2));
                        this.SelectedObjectIndex = 0;
                    });
        }
```

This solution loads the list, but the first element is not displayed correctly in the picker.

How can i populate the picker and display the first element the right way?

Comment: When you say "the first element is not displayed correctly in the picker" what does that means? You have an image of how it looks?

Comment: @apineda it only desplays the first character (!) of the string in the picker. thats very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at your code and I believe the problem you have (for the 10% of the fails) is because you are using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your async call.

Reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) it clearly states that using `ConfigureAwait` when you will later manipulate the UI could cause problem because of the context. This is why you are forced to use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to prevent a crash.

So removing the `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the async call should resolve the issue of your 10% fails.

For the issue with the string showing only the first characters I couldn't reproduce it. My suggestion would be to print out the values before doing any other conversion/concatenation.

**Note**: The concatenation you are doing could also be done like this:

```
this.ObjectList.Add ($"{f.attr1} - {f.attr2}");
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I use ConfigureAwait everywhere in my app to prevent a blocking UI thread, but it seems that i can remove it in this special method.